# SQL - Retrieving data within groups before and after some condition

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

With the two following tables:

- `EMPLOYEE (Fname, Lname, SSN, DNO)`
- `DEPARTMENT (Dname, Dnumber)`

> For each department that has more than five employees, retrieve the
>   department name and the number of its employees who are making more
>   than $40,000

Here is an incorrect solution to this:

```
SELECT 
    dname, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    Department, Employee 
WHERE 
    dnumber = dno 
    AND salary > 40000 
GROUP BY 
    dname 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 5;
```

It is clear that it would not list any department that have five or more employees unless they all have more than $40,000 salary, because where is applied before group by clause. which is not what we want.

Here is the correct solution:

```
SELECT
    dname, COUNT(*) 
FROM
    Department, Employee 
WHERE 
    dnumber = dno 
    AND salary > 40000 
    AND dno IN (SELECT dno 
                FROM Employee 
                GROUP BY dno 
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 5) 
GROUP BY
    dname
```

I cant see why is this correct?

Isn't it going to restrict the rows first with employees who have more than $40,000, then do the grouping just like the first query? what is different here?

Comment: The order of conditions doesn't matter. The subquery returns the list of departments with more than 5 employees. The outer Select returns employees from those  departments with a salary above 40000. Highlight the subquery and check its result.

Comment: if a department has 6 employees and one has 40k salary while the rest of 5 emp have 50k salary then the 1st query will not return this department. Getting departments with 6 or more employees then getting higly paid employees (40k) IS NOT THE SAME with get departments with 6 or more employees with >40k salaries.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ yes but isn't the 2nd query doing this just like the first one?

Comment: `because where is applied before group by clause` The order of the clauses is fixed. The syntax just requires this.

Comment: nope. the sequence in 1st query is give me emp with >40k per department then count them if they are > 5. for 2nd query, get departments with > 5 employees then give me emp with > 40k salary.

Comment: On a sidenote: It seems you are learning from a very old book or tutorial. Comma-separated joins where made redunant more than 25 years ago. We are using explicit joins since then (`from department d inner join employee e on e.dno = d.dnumber`). We also wouldn't give the same attribute two different names (`dno` vs. `dnumber`). Maybe you should switch to something better to learn from.

Comment: There it is, I've finished my long post, take your time to read ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Sub-Query, the basic:

First, let make this query a bit easier to read :

```
SELECT 
    dname, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    Department, 
    Employee 
WHERE 
    dnumber = dno 
    AND salary > 40000 
    AND dno IN (
        SELECT dno 
        FROM Employee 
        GROUP BY dno
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
    ) 
GROUP BY dname
```

As you can see, there is what we call a "sub-query": a query inside the query.

This is the part in `dno IN (/*HERE is the Sub-query*/)`.

As in mathematics parenthesis are run first, so SQL will go find DNO that have more than 5 employees, producing the following query :

```
SELECT 
    dname, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    Department, 
    Employee 
WHERE 
    dnumber = dno 
    AND salary > 40000 
    AND dno IN (
        'dno10emp', 'dno24emp', 'dno45emp'
    ) 
GROUP BY dname
```

Now, you find yourself with a simple query that will produce the result:

- of department that have a least one employee with >40k$ salary
- and are part of the department with more the 5 employee

---

## What's wrong ?!

Well, I'll said your "good query" isn't that good, and that's why you're struggling: It'll not bring department if they don't have at least one employee with > 40k$.

Here is the query that'll do this :

```
SELECT 
    Department.dname, 
    COUNT(Employee.salary) 
FROM 
    Department
LEFT JOIN Employee
    ON Department.dnumber = Employee.dno
        AND Employee.salary > 40000 
WHERE 
    Department.dnumber IN (
        SELECT Employee.dno 
        FROM Employee 
        GROUP BY Employee.dno
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
    )
GROUP BY Department.dname
```

This will bring you all department that have at least 6 employee, then count the number of employee with at least 40K$ (a department could have 0).

---

## Could you show me ?

As an image worth a thousand word :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/338f7c/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
|             dname | nb | salary |
|-------------------|----|--------|
|        accounting |  2 |  30000 |
|        accounting |  4 |  50000 |
|              boss |  6 | 150000 |
| garbage-collector |  6 |  15000 |
```

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT 
        dname, 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        Department, 
        Employee 
    WHERE 
        dnumber = dno 
        AND salary > 40000 
    GROUP BY dname 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/338f7c/1/0)**:

```
| dname | COUNT(*) |
|-------|----------|
|  boss |        6 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
    SELECT 
        dname, 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        Department, 
        Employee 
    WHERE 
        dnumber = dno 
        AND salary > 40000 
        AND 
        dno IN (
            SELECT dno FROM Employee 
            GROUP BY dno
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
        ) 
    GROUP BY dname
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/338f7c/1/1)**:

```
|      dname | COUNT(*) |
|------------|----------|
| accounting |        4 |
|       boss |        6 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
    SELECT 
        Department.dname,
        COUNT(Employee.salary) 
    FROM 
        Department
    LEFT JOIN Employee
        ON Department.dnumber = Employee.dno
            AND Employee.salary > 40000 
    WHERE 
        Department.dnumber IN (
            SELECT Employee.dno 
            FROM Employee 
            GROUP BY Employee.dno
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
        )
    GROUP BY Department.dname
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/338f7c/1/2)**:

```
|             dname | COUNT(Employee.salary) |
|-------------------|------------------------|
|        accounting |                      4 |
|              boss |                      6 |
| garbage-collector |                      0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

See sample data below.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/357d29/2

The first query will only get departments with 6 or more highy paid employees WHILE the 2nd query will get highly paid employees of those departments with 6 or more employees. Below sample will not show in the 1st query but will show in the 2nd query.

```
Department  Employee   Salary
 accounting   john doe      50k
                        jan  smith    55k
                       dan brown   60k
                       eric murphy 60k
                       al  daniels    70k
                       ellen boyle   30k

1st query: nothing because only five emp have > 40k salary
 2nd query: All except ellen boyle. Department has > 5 employees and all except 1 has > 40k salary
```

Comment: As I've shamelessly stolen your sqlfiddle for the sake of my explanation, take a +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you already got correct answers. I'll just try to explain it in a different way.

Your first query has 1 select statement. It only returns employees with salary > 40k and from departments > 5 employees. Every record will only contain information about an employee with salary > 40k and from departments > 5 employees.

Your second query has 2 select statements:

This is the first one:

```
 Select dname, count(*) 
  from Department, Employee 
 where dnumber = dno 
   and salary > 40000
```

it returns the count of all employees, by department name who earn > 40000. There are no conditions on the count(*) here. And the condition on the salary has no power over the second select statement:

```
 SELECT Employee.dno 
   FROM Employee 
   GROUP BY Employee.dno
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

This one returns ALL employees in all departments. This is where we have the condition on the count(*) - but it is only applied locally, to limit the number of employees per department.

And then two statements are joined together - so, first we limit the departments to the ones we are interested in, and then from those only select high-salary employees.

Answer (score 0):

First, never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

I think the best and simplest solution uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT d.dname, SUM(CASE WHEN e.salary > 40000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_40kplus
FROM Department d JOIN
     Employee e
     ON d.dno = e.dnumber
GROUP BY dname 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

I see no reason why a subquery would be necessary or desirable.